# Example of a linear onto map which is not open

Tags: functional-analysis

We know that every linear open map between normed spaces is onto. This fact actually motivates the Open Mapping theorem which gives extra assumptions for converse to hold true. But I am unable to construct counterexample for the first fact, i.e. I am looking for a linear map between normed spaces which is onto but not open. Any hint for such map. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the identity
$$I : (\ell^1, \|\cdot\|_1) \to (\ell^1, \|\cdot\|_\infty)$$
which is a continuous bijection since $\|\cdot\|_\infty \le \|\cdot\|_1$. However, it is not open.

Indeed, if $I$ were open, it would imply that $I^{-1}$ is bounded i.e. that $\|\cdot\|_1$ is bounded by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, which is false.

Comment: I knew this fact that $\|\cdot\|_1$ is not bounded by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ but I am not coming with proper logic now how to show this. Can you give some hint.

Comment: @Believer For $n \in \Bbb{N}$ consider $x_n = (\underbrace{1, 1, \ldots, 1}_n, 0, 0).$
We have $\|x_n\|_1 = n$ but $\|x_n\|_\infty = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\mathfrak{c}_{00} = \{\text{sequences } f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ with } f(n) \neq 0 \text{ for finitely many } $n$ \}$, normed by supremum. A Hamel basis for $\mathfrak{c}_{00}$ is given by the singleton sequences $f_n : m \to \delta_{mn}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Then consider the map $g: \mathfrak{c}_{00} \to \mathfrak{c}_{00}$ given by $g(f)(n) = \frac{1}{n} f(n)$. Then $g$ is linear, $||g|| = 1$ (and hence $g$ is continuous), and $g$ is onto as for any sequence $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, the sequence $\tilde{f} : n \to nf(n)$ is still an element of $\mathfrak{c}_{00}$ and satisfies $g(\tilde{f}) = f$. However, $g$ is not open, because for any $f$ with $||f|| < 1$, $$g(f)(n) = \frac{1}{n} f(n) < 1/n.$$ So $g(B(0,1))$ contains no neighborhood of $0$.

It's worth mentioning here that we can see exactly why this specific example fails in the completion of $\mathfrak{c}_{00}$. The completion of $\mathfrak{c}_0$ has an explicit description given by $\mathfrak{c}_0 = \{\text{sequences } f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ so } \lim_{n \to \infty}f(n) = 0\}.$ If we define $g$ as above on $\mathfrak{c}_{0}$, $g$ is not onto because $(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, ...) \in \mathfrak{c}_0$, but if it were to happen that $g(f)(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$, then $f(n)$ would need to be $1$ for all $n$. This is impossible for $f \in \mathfrak{c}_0$.

Comment: Your A appeared as I was proof-reading mine.

Comment: @Alex I couldn't figure out why $g(B(0,1))$ contains no nbhd of $0$.

Comment: @Noobmathematician . A nbhd $B$ of $0$ covers$ B(0,r)$ for some $r>0,$ so $(r/2)f_n\in B$ for all $n.$  But if $1/n<r/2$ and $f\in B(0,1)$ then $g(f)\ne (r/2)f_n $ because $g(f)(n)<1/n<r/2=((r/2)f_n)(n).$

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be the set of all $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb R$ such that $\{n\in \Bbb N:f(n)\ne 0\}$ is finite.

For $f,g\in V$ let $\|f-g\|=\max_{n\in \Bbb N}|f(n)-g(n)|. $

And (as usual) for $f,g\in V$ and $n\in \Bbb N$ and $r\in \Bbb R$ let $(f+g)(n)=f(n)+g(n)$ and $(rf)(n)=r\cdot f(n).$

Let $M:V\to V$ where $(M(f))(n)=f(n)/n^2$ for $f\in V$ and $n\in \Bbb N.$

$M$ is linear ( & continuous ). $M$ is also a bijection, so if $M$ was an open map then $M^{-1}$ would be continuous. But $M^{-1}:V\to V$ is linear but unbounded so $M^{-1}$ cannot be continuous.